# Linq and cloning Objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq

This question is not about cloning objects but about the correct use of Linq to use an extension method to clone a list of objects.Code if just for illustration.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           List<MyObj> myObjs = DB.GetAllMyObjs(); //fictitious database calls returns a list of Objs


        //I now want to use my extension method clone to clone all the MyObjs in myObjs
        // this throws an error;
        List<MyObj> myObj2 = myObjs.ForEach(a => a.Clone()).ToList(); //ERROR = "."cannot be applied to type void


    }
}

public class MyObj 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }



}
public static class MyObjExtentions
{
    public static MyObj  Clone(this MyObj myObj)
    {
        var myObjClone = new MyObj();
        myObjClone.Id = myObj.Id;
        return myObjClone;
    }
}
```

}

I am getting an error on the Linq code. is it possible to do this or do you need a foreach loop.

Comment: have you thought of using ICloneable instead of an extension method?

Comment: I am fairly certain that `ForEach` is not LINQ.

Comment: Correct. ´ForEach()´ is a method on `List(T)`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx. The big difference is that all LINQ extensions returns something and is immutable by nature. `ForEach`can be used to manipulate the objects which is iterated on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `ForEach` To `Select`

```
List<MyObj> myObj2 = myObjs.Select(a => a.Clone()).ToList();
```

ForEach is part of the list implementation. not linq